# SQL Server, parse a text which has multiple lines of html code into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, loops, parsing

I have a skeleton of a code which I began to write for the following purpose:

```
use EAS
go
  declare @entityID,int
  declare @text,text
  declare @col1,varchar --col1 is between <b>col1</b>
  declare @col2,varchar   --col2 are between >col2</td>

  @entityID=entity_ID
  @text = maAttributes_Text.value
  @col1 = select SUBSTRING(@text,CHARINDEX('<b>',@text)+len('<b>'),
  charindex('</b>',@text))
  @col2 = select substring(@text, CHARINDEX('>',@text)+LEN('>'),charindex('</td>',@text))

  begin
  add to `table2` [entity_id], [caption], [value]
  @entityID, @col1, @col2
  end
```

I need to access a different table, `table1`, which contains fields `entity_id`, `caption` and `value`, as well as a few others which are unimportant.

```
entity_id | caption      | value
----------|--------------|-------
12345     |Specifications| *html snippet*
```

What my code is supposed to do is, to find rows in `table1` which have the value of 'Specifications' in field `caption`, then extract the entity_id value, store it, and then run a loop which takes all the rows of the html table and adds the info into another sql table.

For example, after running the code for one line of `table1`, `table2` will look like as follows:

```
table2
entity_ID|Caption|Value
---------|-------|-----
12345    |length |10
12345    |width  |10
12345    |height |10
et al.
```

Where all the information in `table2` came from the html snippet which is stored in `value` field of `table1`.

My instincts tell me that I should use both a loop (I cannot make a loop in sql for the life of me) and the STRING_SPLIT function. However, I am not sure how to implement them.

After finishing the first row of `table1`, it will continue to the next row and the next row, as many rows `WHERE caption in ('specifications')`

EDIT: I understand my wording was pretty confusing. I will try to reexplain.

I have `table1` which contains an ID number which is tied to an html snippet. The html snippet is the code for a table which contains many rows and two columns. My desired function will take the html snippet and parse it by row, and add it to `table2` where the one ID number from `table1` will be attached to the several rows of the html table. Therefore when the first few rows of the HTML SNIPPET are extracted, `table2` will appear as so:

```
table2
entity_ID|Caption|Value
---------|-------|-----
12345    |length |10
12345    |width  |10
12345    |height |10
```

wherein `entity_ID` is the unique ID number, and it is tied to several rows from within the HTML snippet. `Caption` is taken from `col1` of the html snippet, and `Value` is taken from `col2` of the html snippet.

EDIT 2:
A simple example of my situation:

`table1`

```
ID|Caption       |Value  
--|--------------|-----  
1 |Specifications|*html snippet*  
2 |Specifications|*html snippet2*  
etc.
```

the code will take information from `table1` and put it into `table2' as follows:

`table2`

```
ID|SpecName|Spec    
--|--------|----  
1 |Length  |10  
1 |Width   |10  
1 |Height  |10
```

SpecName and Spec are fields from the html table that the html snippet created. Length, Width, Height are the information that the snippet is producing. 10, is the value for each of the SpecNames.

```html
<table  class="inline_sd_table"> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Accessories Optional</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Accommodates Ceiling Height</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>ADA Compliance</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">See Additional Information above</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Blower Air Mover Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Fan</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Blower Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Boost Mode</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>CFM (Airflow)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">190</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Color/Finish</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Almond</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Control Feature Filter Reminder</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Damper Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Delay Shut Off</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Digital Clock</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Dishwasher Safe Filters</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Duct Connector Size</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">3-1/4" x 10", 7" Round Non-Ducted</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>ENERGY STAR&reg; qualified</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Filter Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Filter Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Aluminum</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Flue Accommodates ceilings up to xx ft</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Heat Sentry - Temperature Sensor</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>HVI Certified</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Light Bulb Quantity</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">1</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Light Bulbs Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Lighting Function</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">One-level</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Lighting Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Incandescent</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Max Sones/100 CFM</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">4.1</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Minimum Height Above Cook Top</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">18"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Mounting Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Under Cabinet</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Nightlight</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Non-Stick Coated</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Product Depth (inches)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">17-1/2"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Product Height (inches)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Product Width (inches)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">42"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Rated Amps</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">2.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Remote Control</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Sones Certified Horizontal Rectangular High</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Sones Certified Horizontal Rectangular Low</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Rectangular High</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Rectangular Low</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Round High</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Round Low</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Switch Control Settings</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">2</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Switch Style</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Rocker</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Timer</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>UL Listed</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Voltage</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">120</td> </tr> </table>
```

Comment: Are you creating or parsing HTML? Either way, SQL has XML manipulation functions which you should probably be using over string concatenation or substringing.

Comment: @Xedni I am parsing an html snippet which is stored in a cell of a sql table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is a little hard to follow, but does this help?

I modified a Parse/Split function to accept two non-like parameters.  In this case `'>'` and `'<'`.

I should add, the TVF is very performant.  The results are returned in 0.068 seconds.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '<table  class="inline_sd_table"> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Accessories Optional</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Accommodates Ceiling Height</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>ADA Compliance</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">See Additional Information above</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Blower Air Mover Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Fan</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Blower Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Boost Mode</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>CFM (Airflow)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">190</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Color/Finish</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Almond</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Control Feature Filter Reminder</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Damper Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Delay Shut Off</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Digital Clock</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Dishwasher Safe Filters</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Duct Connector Size</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">3-1/4" x 10", 7" Round Non-Ducted</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>ENERGY STAR&reg; qualified</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Filter Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Filter Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Aluminum</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Flue Accommodates ceilings up to xx ft</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Heat Sentry - Temperature Sensor</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>HVI Certified</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Light Bulb Quantity</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">1</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Light Bulbs Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Lighting Function</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">One-level</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Lighting Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Incandescent</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Max Sones/100 CFM</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">4.1</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Minimum Height Above Cook Top</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">18"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Mounting Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Under Cabinet</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Nightlight</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Non-Stick Coated</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Product Depth (inches)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">17-1/2"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Product Height (inches)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Product Width (inches)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">42"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Rated Amps</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">2.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Remote Control</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Sones Certified Horizontal Rectangular High</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Sones Certified Horizontal Rectangular Low</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Rectangular High</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Rectangular Low</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Round High</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Round Low</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Switch Control Settings</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">2</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Switch Style</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Rocker</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Timer</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>UL Listed</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Voltage</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">120</td> </tr> </table> '

Select Item  = max(case when RetCol=1 then RetVal end)
      ,Value = max(case when RetCol=0 then RetVal end)
 From (
        Select RetGrp=(Row_Number() over (Order By RetSeq)-1)/2
              ,RetCol=Row_Number() over (Order By RetSeq) % 2 
              ,RetPos
              ,RetVal
         From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](@S,'>','<')
         Where RetVal>''
      ) A
 Group By RetGrp
 Order By RetGrp
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

> **EDIT - Illustration of Raw Results**

If you were to simply run

```
Select * from  [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](@S,'>','<')
```

The Results would be:

[image]

Comment: The results you received are almost exactly what I am looking for. However, I do not understand how the function works. For instance why does the function know when exactly to extract the text, because there are other cases where there is text (or whitespace) between `>` and `<`, which is undesired information.

Comment: @javajunkee See EDIT

Comment: @javajunkee The beauty of using a TVF is that it can easly be used within a CROSS APPLY (i.e. no looping)

Comment: @JohnCappalletti I understand why blank spaces are not picked up now. If I were to want to implement this code into my sql server, I would need both the UDF and the TVF since the TVF makes a call to the UDF?

Comment: @javajunkee UDF is a generic term.  There are two types of functions (both UDFs).  1 Scalar-Valued Function and 2) Table-Valued Function.   You only need the UDF supplied (which is a TVF).

Comment: @javajunkee If you were to edit your question and provide a simplified sample (far less detail, but key elements and structures), I would be happy to provide an integrated example.

Comment: @javajunkee Added a second answer illustrating the use of a TVF within a CROSS APPLY

Comment: @JohnCappalletti I made a second edit to my question, I hope it is a simpler example. Another useful piece of information is that this code will have to work on `table1` which contains many rows. Performance is not as important to me as getting the job done.

Answer (score 2):

What about this? Note, I had to update the HTML blob because it had an unencoded `&`, so I just manually changed it to `&amp;`. But as long as that's set up, this should work:

```
declare @x xml = cast('<table  class="inline_sd_table"> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Accessories Optional</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Accommodates Ceiling Height</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>ADA Compliance</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">See Additional Information above</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Blower Air Mover Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Fan</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Blower Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Boost Mode</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>CFM (Airflow)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">190</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Color/Finish</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Almond</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Control Feature Filter Reminder</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Damper Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Delay Shut Off</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Digital Clock</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Dishwasher Safe Filters</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Duct Connector Size</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">3-1/4" x 10", 7" Round Non-Ducted</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>ENERGY STAR&amp;reg; qualified</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Filter Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Filter Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Aluminum</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Flue Accommodates ceilings up to xx ft</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Heat Sentry - Temperature Sensor</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>HVI Certified</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Light Bulb Quantity</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">1</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Light Bulbs Included</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Lighting Function</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">One-level</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Lighting Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Incandescent</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Max Sones/100 CFM</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">4.1</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Minimum Height Above Cook Top</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">18"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Mounting Type</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">Under Cabinet</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Nightlight</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Non-Stick Coated</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Product Depth (inches)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">17-1/2"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Product Height (inches)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Product Width (inches)</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">42"</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Rated Amps</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">2.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Remote Control</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Sones Certified Horizontal Rectangular High</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Sones Certified Horizontal Rectangular Low</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Rectangular High</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Rectangular Low</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Round High</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">6.5</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Sones Certified Vertical Round Low</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">N/A</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Switch Control Settings</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">2</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>Switch Style</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Rocker</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Timer</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">No</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell"><b>UL Listed</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_odd_cell">Yes</td> </tr> <tr class="inline_sd_cell_row">      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell"><b>Voltage</b></td>      <td class="inline_sd_even_cell">120</td> </tr> </table> ' as xml)


select 
    Name = t.c.value('(td/b)[1]', 'varchar(250)'),
    Value = t.c.value('(td)[2]', 'varchar(250)')
from @x.nodes('/table/tr') as t(c)
```

Comment: A good solution, and my first thought as well.  I just did want to chase the XML characters  +1

Comment: Took the liberty of adding a dbFiddle so OP can see a working example.   http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2a289199dc73814a6b3f0222bb431bff

Answer (score 1):

**Example of Using a TVF within a CROSS APPLY**

```
Insert Into Table2
Select ID = A.Entity_ID
      ,B.*
 From Table1 A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top 10000
                       SpecName  = max(case when RetCol=1 then RetVal end)
                      ,Spec      = max(case when RetCol=0 then RetVal end)
                 From (
                        Select RetGrp=(Row_Number() over (Order By RetSeq)-1)/2
                              ,RetCol=Row_Number() over (Order By RetSeq) % 2 
                              ,RetPos
                              ,RetVal
                         From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.value,'>','<')
                         Where RetVal>''
                      ) B1
                 Group By RetGrp
                 Order By RetGrp
             ) B


Select * from Table2
```

Comment: This is precisely what I am looking for. How would I modify this so that instead of inserting String values on the second line, the values will be pulled from `table1` so that I can be looped for all rows of `table1`?

Comment: @JognCappelletti I apologize for the nuisance, but where is `[dbo].[udf-Str-Extract]` coming from? Is it an object you created?

Comment: @javajunkee in my first answer I included the function  look under "The UDF if Interested"

Comment: @javajunkee FYI, feel free to rename it .  Many do like my naming conventions.

Comment: I ran this without the insert, and I was getting errors around row 13, which I figured out was the `A.value` clause. So I replaced it with a variable that simply holds the html snippet and figured I would write a loop to work through all the rows of `table1`, but then sql began spitting out the first row of the html table thousands of times. Please advise?

Comment: @javajunkee I thought A.Value was your HTML Snippet

Comment: @javajunkee added a third answer with a small sample of html

Comment: A.Value is my html snippet. But for some reason I always get a syntax error around A.Value and I do not know why it is being thrown.

Comment: @javajunkee What datatype is Value ?  varchar, text, or even xml?

Comment: value is a text field.

Comment: Does a straight parse cause an error Select B.* From  Table1 A Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.value,'>','<') B

Comment: @javajunkee You may not have gotten the message above ... AND... have you tried this one  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2a289199dc73814a6b3f0222bb431bff

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. You want me to run that where? And I have tried it, but I get another error on `value` in the replace function. The data type is invalid

Comment: @javajunkee what is the name of the field that contains the html snippet?

Comment: The name is `value`. The exact location is `dbo.maAttributes_Text.value`

Comment: @javajunkee and you changed Table1 to dbo.maAttributes_Text  ?

Comment: yes I changed all the proper terms to match my case.

Comment: @javajunkee This may be very simple ....  Didn't occur to me.  We have to convert value to varchar(max).   So where you have "Value"  make it  convert(varchar(max),value)

Comment: @javajunkee I have a client lunch.  Be back 1:30'ish.   If the above fails, but together some screen shot (I'm a visual girl) and email them to me at john.m.cappelletti  -- gmail.

Comment: I had tried converting earlier, but I still hit an error. It then says that `value` is an incorrect column name. I try putting the exact name, but to no avail.